# React router 'Page Not Found' page not showing when Routes defined inside div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have some routes which I have added header, div and sidemenu .
Outside of these I have added 'Page Not Found ' Route. But when I hit invalid URL it's not showing 'Page Not Found' page

I have tried putting all routes together inside the 'div' but I don't require these div, header, sidemenu for 'Page Not Found' page

```
<Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={LoginPage} />
            <Route path="/ShowReport" component={ShowReport} />

            <div className="container-fluid py-5">
              <Header />
              <Notify />
              <div className="row justify-content-center pt-2">
                <Sidemenu />
                <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
                <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
              </div>
            </div>
            <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
          </Switch>
```

Expected Result is: When I hit invalid URL should show page not found without header, sidemnu.

Answer (score 2):

You are using it the wrong way. Try it this way:

```js
// import 
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

// your class's return
return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path="/ShowReport" component={ShowReport} />

        <div className="container-fluid py-5">
          <Header />
          <Notify />
          <div className="row justify-content-center pt-2">
            <Sidemenu />
            <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
            <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
       </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
```

Comment: Change the structure of how you are showing NotFoundPage.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your example here in sandbox: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic and got `Invariant failed: You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>` error.

Try to wrap your `Switch` with `Router` imported like:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main example for [routing a No-Match](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match), the Switch element is wrapped in a Router element like this:

```
 <Router>
     <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={LoginPage} />
            <Route path="/ShowReport" component={ShowReport} />
            <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
     </Switch>
 </Router>
```

If this still does not solve your problem, try temporarily pasting `<Route component={NotFoundPage} />` above the div, does this still show an empty page or does this change anything.

If this causes the notfoundpage to appear, you are passing an unknown prop in your original code (possibly by passing styling?).